# Why can not initiate the script in this case

Tags: jquery

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/easyui/themes/gray/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/easyui/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#closeMe").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .slideUp();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rem">
<span id="closeMe"><img src="http://www.cespage.com/silverlight/appbar/dark/close.png"></span>
<p>Please read the documentation.For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple box with a close button, once press, it slide up. However , when i test it and i press the button, there is no reaction. What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: what browser are you using. some versions of IE wont bind a click event to a non A tag.

Comment: Never heard of that problem before, j_mcnally. Are you sure? In any event, the real problem is that the document isn't ready.

Comment: @j_mcnally - which versions of IE would that be? It's worked for me in every version from 5.5 onwards (I can't remember the versions before that), though I've only used the Windows versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your init code should be inside a `$(document).ready()` call, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#closeMe").click(function() {
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

As is, it's trying to run before the `#closeMe` item even exists. `$(document).ready()` makes sure it waits until the DOM is ready.

Comment: These dang low-hanging fruit questions... beat me by 5 seconds. ;-)

Comment: @GregPettit D'oh! I don't usually try "quick draw" stuff, but I figured I'd give this a shot! hehe

Answer (score 0):

wrap the code inside the ready handler

```
$(function(){    
 $("#closeMe").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .slideUp();
   });    
 });
```

or alternatively move the script at the end of your document like

```
<body>
<div id="rem">
<span id="closeMe"><img src="http://www.cespage.com/silverlight/appbar/dark/close.png"></span>
<p>Please read the documentation.For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.</p>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#closeMe").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .slideUp();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your jquery function so it work on page completion:

```
$(function() {

   $("#closeMe").click(function() {
       $(this).parent().slideUp();
   });

}
```